# How can I configure emacs on Windows to translate path '~'?

Tags: windows, emacs

I am running emacs on Windows 7.
How can I configure emacs on Windows to translate path '~' to a specified directory I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(setenv "HOME" "E:/water")
(setq default-directory "~/")
```